# How do I validate a related record exists when a field is updated

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am pretty new but am trying to learn through doing. I have a Profile model and Vendor model which are related as follows:

```
class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :vendor, dependent: :destroy
end

class Vendor < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :profile
end
```

The Profile model has a field called :verified_vendor which is a bool that is default false for all profiles. The Vendor model for now has only one field but we will be adding more later, that field is :reference_account_num. Once we do some in-house financials logic, I have set up a route in our app where the admin will go in and select the Profile, select to verify the profile as a vendor, then enter the vendor reference account number they created in the financial system. The application then creates a vendor row and updates the profile to verified as true. I want to make sure that I validate that a row must be created when the flag is flipped. I have looked at doing this through an observer, but is that the right path? Since the flag is in the Profile it seems I can update the :reference_account_num field and it breaks my business logic because the vendor information doesn't have to be created.

1. Admin selects a profile and selects verify as vendor
2. Admin enters the financial reference number
3. The transaction creates a vendor row and updates the profile :verified_vendor to true

Comment: have you looked into after_update callbacks?

Comment: This is the part I'm confused about - if I hook into after_update, will it transact together, or will the update occur first and then the hook fire off and possibly fail, thereby breaking integrity?

Comment: after_update will run after the changes have been saved, if you want to check for integrity and have the save fail, use before_update, if you return false, it will stop the saving process, you can also stick in error messages to the instance at this point too. If you'd like I'll whip up some sample code in the answer.